# Using previous hour's value in time series data for inclusion in random forest

Tags: python, regression, random-forest

I have a training data set, which is something like the following:

```
hour   windspeed   pollution
0              5           8
1              6           9
2              3           1
```

I am using scipy's RandomForestRegressor to estimate *pollution* given *windspeed, hour*. It is doing "ok", with $r^2 = 0.7$ and $rmse = 35$. However, I would like to include the previous hours *pollution values* as additional predictors, as in:

```
hour   windspeed   pollution   pollution@t-1  polluion@t-2 ... pollution@t-n
0              5           8              NA           NA                 
1              6           9               8           NA
2              3           1               9           8
```

Eventually, I will be applying this to future weather conditions, estimating pollution, where pollution can only be known at time zero:

```
hour   windspeed  pollution  p@t-1  p@t-2  p@t-3  p@t-4    ...
1              5          ?     34     28     25     ...   ...         
2              6          ?     NA     34     28      25   ... 
3              3          ?     NA     NA     34      28   ...
```

How should I best go about including this in a Random Forest? Since RFs don't tolerate null values, how best to impute them? Since '0' is not appropriate (given that 0 is likely very far from the current value), I was thinking that perhaps NaNs could be filled with the nearest known value, as in:

```
hour   windspeed  pollution  p@t-1  p@t-2  p@t-3  p@t-4    ...
1              5          ?     34     28     25     ...   ...         
2              6          ?     34     34     28      25   ... 
3              3          ?     34     34     34      28   ...
```

Comment: [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49270/imputation-with-random-forests) has a helpful, possibly duplicate answer.